Usage of であって here? What does it add?

The protagonist asks "didn't you say I was a good listened?" but the character rebukes him and says this.
I fundamentally get what it's being said (he explains a good listener is someone who skillfully draws out what his partner wants to say and makes him call, and the MC is just someone who listens instead) but what does であって here adds exactly?

Does that answer your question? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/43222/function-of-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6

It's the te-form of である, which is a literary version of だ. Etymologically, だ is corrupted である. である is a bookish copula that sounds pompous if used at the end of a sentence in speech. However, である in the middle of a sentence tends to be accepted in serious speech. And this なのであって is even necessary because なので (te-form of なのだ) is taken as a reason marker ので:

～を聞き上手と言うので、…
A good listener refers to ～, so ...
～を聞き上手と言うのであって、…
A good listener refers to ～, and ...

He avoided the meaning of "so" or "thus" by using のであって.
